# What home printer would allow for exact alignment of front and back?

Tags: print-design, alignment, print-production

Note: I'm not a graphic designer, but this seemed like the most relevant place to post. Feel free to send me off somewhere else if I'm not in the right place.

I would like to make some notebooks with double-sided grid paper that I've already designed, but my printer seems like it doesn't allow for absolutely exact alignment. Even if one side prints nice and straight, the other side will be slightly skewed left to right by one to two millimeters, which I read from an earlier post is a pretty reasonable variance for a home printer. So I suspect it's not possible to get both sides completely aligned on this printer – but if I'm wrong, please let me know how.

What kind of printer would allow for absolutely exact alignment? Is there any difference between inkjet and laser in this regard, or a more expensive printer versus a cheaper one?

Comment: Commenting because though this may not help you, it may be of use to others who find this question via Google: though, as the answers below state, you're unlikely to find a home printer that will give you alignment better than a few millimetres, a solution in many cases is to adjust the design so that it doesn't matter - so, for example, if designing playing cards, design the back such that it has a relatively wide border in a uniform colour, and give it a lot of "bleed" (extra colour extending beyond the edge of the card) so that when the playing card is cut out, any misalignment won't show.

Comment: Note that there is an Arts and Crafts stack exchange: https://crafts.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @psmears That's actually really helpful for me too. It's not ideal, but I can redesign things so there's a white border around it. That would probably work. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I have a cheap Brother laser printer.  When I print a sheet, then refeed it and reprint it, it seems to print in a pretty repeatable manner (text not very distorted or shifted).  If your printer is the same, then you can measure the front-to-back registration difference, then move your backside image to compensate.  So your front and back page margins would be different in the file, but *print*, on your machine, in alignment.

Comment: Note that running a printed sheet through a *laser printer* not designed for duplex printing (double-sided) will ultimately ruin the fuser, which customarily costs about 2/3 of the total printer cost. In short, you'll ruin your printer. Which may be fine if it's cost effective to just replace it when needed.

Comment: Just want to say… measure your paper.
I find some paper to be 1mm short of 28cm or 11in.

Answer (score 30):

**None**.

End user printers are not designed for perfect registrations. None of them. It should always be expected that paper will shift and move slightly and **never** be pulled through the printer in the *exact* same way twice. This even includes printers specifically designed for duplex printing. The nature of sheetfed laser or inkjets just does not allow for exact paper feed every time.

The only way to ensure proper registration is to get things printed via a commercial print provider.

Comment: And this includes big solid duplex machines designed for office use -- it's just not something they're built for.  If you have a rule between the header and body of a page and hold a sheet up to the light, the error is often around 1mm.  It's fairly reproducible for a given paper load, so you could reduce but not eliminate it by offsetting the even pages.

Comment: Why could it not be eliminated well enough to be below resolution by using transparent media to calibrate, then indeed using an offset and feeding printing media with precise care?

Comment: Because each and every feed will be different. You *can't* calibrate to a constantly changing variable. Although there may be a range of variance, it is a *range* not a set value. The best you can ever do is get "close". But even that is *highly* dependent upon the actual printer.

Comment: As a printer I feel I should point out that even our digital presses don't have the back-up registration accuracy of a traditional press. Our Kodak NexPress can be off as much as 1/16" front to back easily.

Comment: Thanks @Logarr I suspected as much, but with no direct experience I was hesitant to add that specifically.

Comment: @rackandboneman the feed will be different for different media (different friction, and friction is key).  I doubt you could do better than putting in a whole ream in one go, wasting a few sheets, then printing your calibration (window or light box to check the registration), then the real thing, all in one session.  This assumes a duplex printer (reloading  introduces a random component) and also assumes the printer doesn't heat up enough to change anything.  This last assumption may not be a good one for more than a few sheets.

Comment: @rackandboneman lifting of the paper is actually one of the most complex pieces to engineer in your typical printer. Doing it so that you get very accurate registration would make the printer really expensive. It is certainly possible but wouldnt make much economic sense, this is why the systems depend on a somewhat inaccurate method that can be bjilt cheaply.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if a more expensive/different type of home printer would be built with some guides to minimize the amount of shifting, but it makes sense that it wouldn't be possible. The place where I used to go for professional printing just seems to use a much larger version of a home printer (I mean that's what it looks like at least), so I wasn't sure how that would be different.

Comment: @joojaa any design with a flat printing bed could simply... make that bed translucent and let a cheap camera watch it from below.

Comment: @rackandboneman yes but that would raise the cost by atleast 100 dollars for a feature that very few need. It would also make the printer larger as nearly all printers print on the paper when it curves. But luckily for us  you do not need a flat bed for this (or a camera). Also this is not as simple as it sounds but yes i have implemented this in a paper folding machine. Even just allowing a human to place the paper accurately could solve the issue for 90% of users  that need any sort of alignment.

Comment: Would an old-fashioned tractor-feed printer allow the sort of front-back registration needed?

Answer (score 19):

The only kind of sheet fed printers I know of that can achieve accurate registration are printing presses. They have suckers to lift each sheet, and mechanical lays to push or pull the paper into the exact same position for printing.

This is what they typically look like
[image: Printing press sheet feeder]

I've never seen anything like this for home or office digital printers like inkjets or laser printers. They have simple feed rollers that feed the sheets by friction.  So your only real option is to have the paper printed commercially on a press.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering what kind of printer allows for accurate alignment, even if it's not something I could ever use or afford. So I think this answers my question.

Comment: And even a printing press isn't perfect. Systems responsible for printing plates for a press create traps (small adjustments/overlaps where two colors meet) and overprints to hide gaps created by misregistration and the normal stretching of plates over a run.

Comment: Thanks @Quint. I imagine that it must be pretty complicated to get an 
accurate print when you have to lay colors over each other. But what if it's just one color?

Comment: @IrvineWizards - but it's not just one colour.  In sheet fed offset lithography, it generally requires two passes through the press to print both sides - unless it's like a duplex web offset press which can print two sides at once, such as those used for printing newspapers.

Comment: What do you mean by "mechanical lays", and how do they provide better registration? [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mechanical+lay) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lay) didn't turn anything up.

Comment: I wonder what sort of precision tractor feed printers could achieve if the width was adjusted to be fairly tight, but not enough to distort the holes in the paper?

Comment: @user2357112 A lay is an edge (sometimes a front/side lay) to which the sheet of paper is pushed or pulled to register the sheet in the same position each time. Sometimes a side lay moves mechanically to push the sheet into position, other types are a kind of stroker lay which pulls the paper into position. There are different types depending on the kind of press/manufacturer.

Comment: @user2357112, if you are interested in learning more there is an example here on youtube showing how the feeder is set up on a Heidelberg GTO lithographic press. https://youtu.be/Igw5GR9mz3s?t=4m27s

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you need to "print", a plotter-type device might work for you.  These are typically sold for home use as vinyl/paper cutting machines, but some also have pen attachments for drawing line art.

This page on [Silhouette's website](https://www.silhouetteamerica.com/how-to/?slug=sketch-pen) shows one of the products in action.

For this to work, you could only "print" line art, and production speed would be low because you'd have to manually flip over the paper and ensure it was lined up perfectly on one of the marked mats that feed sheets into the machine.  I've been able to get pretty accurate results when using the cutting heads, and the pens work exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks! The Silhouette looks interesting. How long does it take to position and print one page? I'm guessing it will take way too long for my purposes, but it's worth asking.

Comment: You might also look at old pen plotters on EBay. Some of the old ones had a fixed tray where the paper went- they should be able to get pretty good alignment.

Comment: When looking at the various craft cutters, look at how they feed. I know the one my wife has uses a sticky mat that feeds via friction rollers. In the end it's still got a lot of slop in the system.

Comment: @IrvineWizards: In fact I have one of the Silhoutte machines. They're fantastic, but on their own they're not that great for solving this particular problem - the feed mechanism is no more accurate than a home printer. The machine does have a sensor that can align its cuts to marks printed on the page - but only on one side. What you can do with them, though (going back to the playing card example from my comment above) is print on both sides, with bleed on the back, then use the Silhouette to cut out the front. I made some Monopoly-like cards exactly like this, and it worked well.

Comment: If a printer can move the paper bidirectionally without letting go of it, it might be possible to print one side of the paper including a test pattern on one edge, then print the test pattern on another side and move that edge where it can be inspected without letting go of the paper.  A user could then shine a light through the paper, input information about how the test patterns relate, and then have a program print the other side of the page using the alignment information from the test pattern.

Comment: @supercat: That's an interesting thought. The Silhouette machines can move the paper in both directions, and always return the paper to the same place at the end of printing. Their accuracy within a page (ie without taking the paper out / reloading it) is much better (fraction of a millimetre). So that would work in theory - now someone just needs to develop the necessary software ;-)

Comment: @psmears: I just thought of another variation that might be easier to use: start with custom-printed paper that has test patterns already marked on the front and back in perfect alignment.  Printing a half-inch test pattern with six zones [60 lines/inch horizontal; 56 lines/inch horizontal; 60 vertical; 56 vertical; 56 horizontal; 60 horizontal) onto a suitably-printed form could cause some letters to appear that would tell the computer the X shift in the top center, and the Y shift at the top-left and top-right.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, there are probably no personal, mechanical printers with the type of accuracy that you want. However, you can still accomplish it at home through silk screening ([screen printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_printing)).

With a bit of setup you can align the paper (registration), silk screen one side, turn it over, align it again, and silk screen the other side. I recommend doing one side in a batch and then the other side in a batch, in order to give the ink a little drying time.

Here is a detailed explanation of the full process:

[The Printing Process: Screen Printing](http://ohsobeautifulpaper.com/2011/04/the-printing-process-screen-printing/)

Here is a product that makes making the stencil quick and simple:

[EZScreen](https://ezscreenprint.com)

Note that I have never used this product and have no experience or connection with it. I’m mentioning it solely to show that there are ways of making screen printing much easier than it used to be. It’s also likely that there are lots of kits at your local craft or hobby shop and you can find supplies on sites like Amazon too.

Once you have the setup you should be able to quickly turn out your lined pages in nearly any quantity you need, nearly any time you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Its called "registration", and you can improve it by specifying offsets in the printer based on your measurements. Typically you print targets (crosses) in four corners of the page (also known as registration targets, and often an option in advanced page composition software). The targets can be seen by either looking at a double sided page through strong light, or better, printed on a transparency.

Obviously there are limits to this based on the accuracy of the printer. If it is moving from page to page, that is your limit of accuracy. Using the above method you will find out rapidly what that accuracy limit is.

Why would you want to do this? Its standard for printing books.