# Printing unwanted offset

Tags: print-design

I have a question for you guys. I design graphic stuff like invitations etc. I am in cooperation with some printing company but we have a problem.

They use Xerox C75 and I print on 330x488 eco paper (250g). The problem is that there are four invitation on one piece of paper. They cut it on the machine but there is huge offset (about 4mm) between first and last invitation.

It cannot happen because it looks ugly. They say that it's normal that printer is moving its printouts a little bit and when they cut it on the machine this happens and there is nothing we can do about it.

Please tell me if it's true. This printer costs about $10k, i don't believe that there is offset for about 4mm betwen first and 20th piece of paper in the printout.

Comment: See here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/93163/what-home-printer-would-allow-for-exact-alignment-of-front-and-back/93165#93165 - Even the Xerox C75 is just a high end sheet fed copier, that's all. It is not a commercial printing press capable of multi-pass registration. If you need multi-pass registration, you need an *actual printing press* not a copier/printer.

Comment: @Metis Thanks for answer. It makes sense for me but when every printout is moved slighty in any direction. But how to explain that each and each printout is moved more to the right. First printout was at position 0 and last one (20th) was on position 4mm. I believe if I have more sheets to print it will move even more.

Comment: There's really no rhyme or reason to the shifting. Think of it this way.. first sheet gets fed,, as it's pulled into the printer/copier by its right edge, the *next* sheet shifts to the grippers .05mm. So the second sheet is .05mm off... second sheet gets pulled in moving the third sheet .1mm closer.... and so on. There's really little you can do about this other than move to a commercial printing press if 4mm is critical.

Comment: Does putting sheet by sheet help?

Comment: Not really. The nature of such machines is that the grippers may "slip" a minute amount. This is why reproduction via printer/copier is so much cheaper than an actual press. If 4mm is unacceptable, you need to use an offset press.

Comment: Thank you very much for help Metis. I will think about it then

Answer (score 1):

I have seen more expensive machines and all digital ones have that same problem.

My only recommendation is that you prepare a design with generous margins and bleeding so this offset is minimized visually.