# ink / laser printer at the same time?

Tags: print-design, ink

I have printed an image with my ink jet printer, an now I want to add some foil on it, for this I need to print on top of it with a toner, however when I put the image on my laser printer it is never printing on the desired areas, there's always misalignment of 0.5/1 cm.. how can I fix this ? is there any printer that can print ink and toner at same time ? or is there any other solution to add toner ? I tried the toner pen but it wasn't a good, the best results are from a laser printer. I don't wanna do the toner on another paper and then cut it and pasted to my original paper... I want to do both on same paper. any solution ?

Comment: Hi user58503, Welcome to Graphic Design on StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What home printer would allow for exact alignment of front and back?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/93163/what-home-printer-would-allow-for-exact-alignment-of-front-and-back) The short and skinny.. it's really impossible to get perfect alignment in the **same** printer, let alone two separate printers.

Comment: @Scott it's impossible to get perfect alignment in all home printers ?

Comment: @user58503 In general.. Yes. If things do *happen* to align it is sheer happenstance. End-use printers are not designed to pull every sheet of paper the same way and position it exactly the same each time. There's always a slight shift in some direction, well at least 99.999% of the time. Some printers will allow *more* of this shifting than others. However, none of them are designed *without* the shift. Imagine throwing 10 playing cards in the air. 8 of the cards are different, 2 are the same. Yes, sometimes both the similar cards will land face up... but you really can't *plan* on that.

Comment: @scott you're right I've been trying on 3 of my home printers none of them gave me perfect result, there's always a slight shift (sometimes right, left, up, down) 
that's weird though, why wouldn't they make home printers that allow perfect alignement just like commercial printers ? I'm sure many people would need this feature

Comment: @user58503 how many end-use printer users would really *care* about perfect alignment... vs.. cost of manufacturing and tolerance quality inspection? And for what it's worth.. running the same sheet of (already printed) paper through a laser printer is **very** bad for the fuser. You'll be replacing that laser printer fuser sooner than you should.

Comment: humm right... do you think the office-jet by HP can do perfect alignment ? if not what are other printers that we can buy to do this ? thank you

Comment: None will. They will **all** have a shift. Even top of the line, 5-figure price tag, digital printers will have a shift. You need a *commercial printing press* to ensure perfect alignment. You simply **can't** *ever* plan on perfect registration if using an end-use printer.

Comment: @Scott okay thank you, I have one last question... what is the best home printer for good alignment? I understand I will never get perfect, but if I get 1mm or 2mm shift it is not a big deal for me.. but my printers go for 0.5cm and even 1 cm sometimes and rarely 1mm or 2mm. Duplex printers maybe ? or you think it is always a question of luck ? can you recommend me some printers ?

Comment: Well there's no real way to tell for certain. It's not something which is *ever* marketed or described in specifications. In general though, higher priced printers may pull and feed sheets slightly more consistently than lower priced models. But really, it's always hit or miss. Again, this is something 99% of the manufacturer's customers don't really care about.

Comment: @scott okay thanks so much for your time and answers

Comment: No problem. `:)` Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. I *wish* there was a "perfect registration" printer out there. But unfortunately there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Heat reactive foil will stick to most any laser printed image; but, sticks best to black toner which has carbon particles encapsulated by the wax toner.

I would suggest that you print the whole job on the laser printer in colour with the areas you want to foil in black. Tricky registration must be done manually.

Trim the foil carefully to cover the black areas on your layout and bond the foil to the artwork with an ordinary clothes iron set to the optimal temperature determined by research and trial an error on scrap artwork. Using the manual iron rather than a roller transport in another machine will allow more precise registration.

I can't be more precise about the bonding temperature due to variations in materials and equipment. It shouldn't take you long to find the best setting. Start low and progress until the edges transfer cleanly. Residue ink can be removed from the iron between colours.

I have used this technique for different foil colours that must neatly touch on the artwork. I made a blue, red, and yellow beachball foil-stamped print using this technique.