# Decent aligned printing on a laser printer? Recommendations?

Tags: alignment, hardware-recommendation, laser

I like to do everything possible at home as I make art prints in small batches. I was really wanting to do full color prints in my inkjet (canon pro 100) and then add foil details by sending them through my laser printer and then hot foiling them. The problem is they come out of my laser printer in a completely different position EVERY time. I know it’s impossible to get perfect alignment prints without professional equipment but I just want something that’s mostly on in the area and not off by 1/3 an inch in any direction every time. Is there any laser printer that someone could recommend that has halfway decent alignment? My canon prints near perfect alignment each time so I’m hoping there’s something in a laser variety out there (and trust me I’ve done tooooons of tests to align things)

Currently I have a Brother HL-L2320

Comment: You should [check this closely related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/93163/89608) and the answers given.  I'm not marking this as an exact duplicate because the other question is about a different problem, but the actual issue (print misregistration) is exactly the same.

Comment: That’s the exact question I saw that did not answer my question and made me create an account on this site to ask my question. Thanks 

Comment: Actually, it kind of is the answer to your question, which is basically that there really aren't any home/office grade laser printers which can control registration. The problem is they aren't designed for it.  Also we don't really do hardware recommendations here anyway. It's generally considered off-topic. Sorry, I know it's probably not what you want to hear.

Comment: Fast/Good/Cheap  Sacrafice one. Your now choosing fast/cheap. You could probably get this if you would sacrafice the automated paper feed. As in you put each paper in manually every time you print. Nobody sells a printer like this though because it would not make economical sense. Note: You cant fix this with just changing one printer youd need to change your laser and your inkjet. Reality though is somebody would need to invent a new paper lifting solution for this to work out.

Comment: 1. Experiment with hand-guiding the paper in. 
2. Put your (smaller) design in the corner with least distortion. 3. Try some friend’s laserprinters (1/3” seeems like a lot) 4. Make your designs more misregistration-proof.

Comment: i just tested my bog-standard HP LaserJet MFP. 1 mm out at the top, close enough for jazz at the bottom.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes but op has misalignment 2 times, once at the inkjet and once at the laser. So expect the problem to be 2 times as large

Comment: I think this is a dupe of the above. Registration is simply not a thing for end use printers.